# Как принудительно закрыть http подключение (сервер на fiber)?

Tags: golang, http, сеть, connection

В fiber (высокоуровневый фреймворк на Go) нет метода для закрытия подключения. Он есть только в fasthttp, поверх которого построен сам фреймворк fiber. Доступ к экземпляру fasthhtp неэкспортирован (поле fasthhtp в структуре fiber.Ctx).
Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все просто. К объектам fasthttp и далее http/net можно получить через c.Context(), где **с** это  *fiber.Ctx

Закрываем соединение без ответа клиенту:

`c.Context().Conn().Close()`